# \refstepcounter{enumi} twice (or more) creates "destination with the same identifier"

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumerate, counters

I fail to understand how the below MWE produces a warning such as this:

```
{c:/.../texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}pdfTeX warning (ext4): desti
nation with the same identifier (name{enumi.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

(This particular format prevents the warning to be picked up by some automatic parsing routines, such as the one in TeXstudio, so I would not be surprised if this is a missed bug somewhere.)

The same warning does not appear if I replace each `\refstepcounter{enumi}` by an `\item`.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{crit:1} This shall be 1
    \end{enumerate}

    Something else.

    \begin{enumerate}
        \refstepcounter{enumi}%
        \refstepcounter{enumi}%
        \item \label{crit:3} This shall be 3
    \end{enumerate} 

    Also, this (\ref{crit:3}) shall be 3, which is why this (\ref{crit:3b}) does not work:

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[3.] \label{crit:3b} This shall be 3
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

After considering @HeikoOberdiek's answer, this is my extended MWE applying his fix to a more general case. Just uncomment the redefinition of `\fixWarning` to see the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\fixWarning}{}
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\fixWarning}{\@hyper@itemfalse\if@nmbrlist\@hyper@itemtrue\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        \fixWarning % the first one removes two warnings
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        \fixWarning % each subsequent one removes a warning each
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        \fixWarning
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        \fixWarning
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        \fixWarning
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        \fixWarning
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        \fixWarning
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        %\fixWarning % not needed!
        \refstepcounter{enumi}
        \item This shall be 10.
    \end{enumerate}

    With \verb|\fixWarning| empty, we receive 8 warnings in the log file.
\end{document}
```

I wonder if `hyperref` should include this fix in the future.

Comment: Well, `\item[...]` does not use `\refstepcounter` and that's why `\@currentlabel` is 'empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `hyperref` patches `\item`:

```
\let\H@item\item
\def\item{%
  \@hyper@itemfalse
  \if@nmbrlist\@hyper@itemtrue\fi
  \H@item
}
```

Since, `\refstepcounter` is used *before* the first `\item`, the inserted patch code needs to be added manually:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \makeatletter
    \@hyper@itemfalse
    \if@nmbrlist\@hyper@itemtrue\fi
    \makeatother
    \refstepcounter{enumi}%
    \refstepcounter{enumi}%
    \item \label{crit:3} This shall be 3
\end{enumerate}
```

The second case with the optional argument

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[3.] \label{crit:3b} This shall be 3
\end{enumerate}
```

is *not* supported in full. One of the problems: Which number is to be derived from `\item[foobar]`?

Comment: After reconsidering the answer, I have been able to apply it to my example. Nonetheless, I wonder if `hyperref` should include this fix in the future.

Comment: @bers Not a good idea: Clean interfaces are missing for `hyperref`, thus `hyperref` has to patch. Further complications of the patch will very certainly lead to compatibility issues with the various package that deal with this kind of environment lists. In summary, a constant maintenance nightmare for a off-label use of `\refstepcounter`.

Answer (score 1):

Heiko Oberdiek already explained the patched `\item` command.

Rather than using `\refstepcounter` I suggest to use the `start=` option of the `enumerate` environment provided by `enumitem`. Please note that `enumitem` uses the start number value as is, i.e. there is no need in order to decrease the number first, i.e. `start=3` will cause `enumerate` to start with `3`.

For the missing reference of `\item[...]` -- there is no `\refstepcounter` used, so no `\@currentlabel` is set. This can be cured by a simple macro named, say `\fakelabel` that displays the label and stores the same content as `\@currentlabel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakelabel}[1]{#1\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{crit:1} This shall be 1
    \end{enumerate}

    Something else.

    \begin{enumerate}[start=3]
    \item \label{crit:3} This shall be 3
    \end{enumerate} 

    Also, this (\ref{crit:3}) shall be 3, which is why this (\ref{crit:3b}) does not work:

    \begin{enumerate}[start=3]
    \item[\fakelabel{foobar} \label{crit:3b}] This shall be foobar!
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good workaround in general, yet I try to avoid using extra packages (such as `enumitem`) for maximum compatibility with publishers. Also, I would expect that something that works without warnings without `hyperref`, should work with `hyperref` just as well.

Comment: @bers: Your decision ;-) Relying on publishers is not the best way to produce nice results